# on delete cascade laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

Morning everyone,

I have foreign keys set to on delete cascade in laravel 5 and mysql on a couple of tables where the existence of a employee depends on the existence of the country he was born in.

```
$table->foreign('id_estado_municipio')
              ->references('id_estado_municipio')
              ->on('cat_municipios')
              ->onDelete('cascade')
              ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Problem is when I delete the country, the employee that must get erased along with it, gets erased from the database, but the employee's record keeps on showing at the index view.

Have tried setting engine to InnoDB in the config file, model observers to delete dependents but still can't figure out how to make it work.

Hopefully someone can give some light. It would be very much appreciate it.

Here you are my models and modelcontrollers

```
class Municipio extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'cat_municipios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_estado_municipio';
    ...

    public function trabajadores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Trabajador::class,'id_trabajador');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($municipio) {
              // delete related stuff ;)
              $municipio -> trabajadores() -> delete();
        });
    }



     class MunicipioController extends Controller
     {
           ...

           public function destroy($id)
           {
                 //
                 $municipio = Municipio::findOrFail($id);
                 $municipio -> trabajadores() -> delete();
                 $destruido = Municipio::destroy($id);
                 if($destruido)
                      return redirect()->route('Municipio.index')->with('info','Municipio eliminado con éxito.');
                 else
                      return redirect()->route('Municipio.index')->with('error','Imposible borrar Municipio.');
            }
      }

////////////////////////////////////////
class Trabajador extends Model
{
//
    protected $table = 'trabajadors';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_trabajador';
...

    public function municipio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Municipio::class,'id_estado_municipio');
    }
    ...
}

 class TrabajadorController extends Controller
 {

      public function index()
      {
          //
          $criterio = \Request::get('search'); //<-- we use global request to get the param of URI

          $estadosciviles = EstadoCivil::orderBy('id_estado_civil')->paginate(50);
    $estados = Estado::orderBy('id_estado') -> paginate(50);
    $municipios = Municipio::orderBy('id_estado_municipio')->paginate();
    $religiones = Religion::orderBy('id_religion')->paginate();

          $trabajadores = Trabajador::where('nombre', 'like', '%'.$criterio.'%')
    ->orwhere('id_trabajador',$criterio)
    ->orwhere('a_paterno',$criterio)
    ->orwhere('a_materno',$criterio)
    ->orwhere('curp',$criterio)
    ->orwhere('rfc',$criterio)
    ->orwhere('seguro_social',$criterio)
    ->sortable()
    ->orderBy('id_trabajador')
    ->orderBy('nombre')
    ->paginate();
    return view('Trabajador.index', array('trabajadores' => $trabajadores,'estadosciviles' => $estadosciviles,'estados' => $estados,'municipios' => $municipios,'religiones' => $religiones));
    }
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Have you verified that the employee(s) in fact are really being deleted from the MySQL table?

Comment: Yes, they are being deleted, in fact, I make sure through both tinker and the mysql graphic interface itself.

I though it might be because of cache issues but information keeps on showing at index after cleaning it.

Thanks.